React Router does not work on direct URLs
I am using React Router and it works normally in dev environment (localhost) but it doesn't work on production. When I access, for example: abc.com/products, it will still say Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ().
I deployed both the client side and server side on Render.
This is my app.ts on the server side:
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import path from 'path';
import apiRouter from './routes/api';

const app = express();

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));

app.use('/api', apiRouter);

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    if (!req.url.startsWith('/api')) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public', 'index.html'));
    }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});

This is my App.tsx on the client side:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Menu from './components/Menu';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Products from './components/Products';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Menu />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/products" element={<Products />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;

This is my Menu.tsx:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Menu = (): JSX.Element => {

    return (
        <div className="menu">
            <div className="main-menu"}>
                <p><span><Link className="redirect" to='/'>HOME</Link></span></p>
                <p className="products-menu"><span><Link className="redirect" to='/products'>PRODUCTS</Link></span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Menu;

How should I fix this?

abc.com/page1 is this for this route or for all routes?

What exactly says "not found", the server? Is this a 404 status error from the server? What server or host service are you using to host and serve your app? Whatever that is needs to be configured to correctly serve the app for any page into the app is being requested. Please [edit] to provide more complete details where you are deploying your app and how you've configured the server.

@DrewReese Sorry I forgot it. I already edited my question. It responded with 404 Error and I deployed my app on Render.

@RakeshRebbavarapu Sorry I already updated my question. I was trying to go to abc.com/products page.

React routers won't work in that way. you can have a server side rendering application with exact same react code(very minute changes) using NextJS.
still if you want to serve this in this way, create _redirects file on the root of the project directory and add following lines  . This is how I hosted react project on Hostinger (second line is enough if you don't have any API routes)
_redirects
/api/*    /api/:splat    200
/*        /index.html    200


The general idea for hosting/serving your client is that the server should return the root index.html file for all page requests into the app. For Render.com this is accomplished by creating Redirect/Rewrite Rule. See Using Client-Side Routing for details.

If you use Reach Router or React Router for client-side routing, you
will need to direct all routing requests to index.html so they can
be handled by your routing library.
You can do this easily by defining a Rewrite Rule for your static
site. Go to the Redirects/Rewrites tab for your service and add a
rule with the following values:




Key
Value




Source Path
/*


Destination Path
/index.html


Action
Rewrite




